# Bypassing Devise database authentication for specific users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have an LDAP authentication for my company's users in the development environment, and I need to be able to allow these users that are authenticated by LDAP to bypass the Devise database auth checks. I have been using create_or_find_by for users that pass the LDAP auth, but I either return "Invalid email or password" for new users or "That password was used previously" for ldap users that are already in the database. I have made these changes in the devise/sessions_controller.rb:

```
def create
    if params[:user][:email].match?(/mycompany.com/)
      ldap_user = LdapAuth.authenticate(params[:user][:email], params[:user][:password])
      if ldap_user.authenticated
        User.find_or_create_by(first_name: params[:user][:email]) do |user|
          user.password = params[:user][:password]
          user.password_confirmation = params[:user][:password]
          user.role = 2
          user.confirmed_at = Time.zone.now
          user.confirmation_sent_at = Time.zone.now
          user.unconfirmed_email = false
          user.first_name = 'Ldap'
          user.last_name = 'User'
          user.save
        end
        super do |user|
          user.user_session_event_logs.create username: user.email,
                                              ip_address: user.current_sign_in_ip,
                                              event_type: :login
        end
      end
    else
      super do |user|
        user.user_session_event_logs.create username: user.email,
                                            ip_address: user.current_sign_in_ip,
                                            event_type: :login
      end
    end
  end
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might sound over simple but you should be able to do something like this

```
...
if ldap_user.authenticated
  sign_in(ldap_user), :bypass => true)
else
  ...
end
...
```

I hope that this helps

Happy coding

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I built a custom work around for this and got it working. This is a nice solution, though. I'll consider this accepted.